# How do I repetitively create global variables from inside a function, each with a different name?

Tags: r

I start with a list of tables, each with the same column names, but different numbers of rows:

```
filenames<- c('name1','name2','etc')
dat<-lapply(paste(filenames,'.csv',sep=""),read.csv)
```

Then I name each table in my list:

```
names(dat)<-filenames
```

Then I write a function to do various things with the data:

```
myfunc<- function (data) {results.table<-some.operations(data)}
```

I want to run my function repetitively over each table in 'dat':

```
lapply(filenames, function(x) myfunc(dat[[x]],x))
```

I am looking for some line to put in 'myfunc' that will create a global output table with a unique name for each table in 'dat' so that I can search these outputs. I understand the global operator <<- creates a global variable, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to assign the names. I tried

```
name<<-results.table
```

but that just assigns each result table to the global variable 'name' so I only have one output at the end - the results for the last table the function ran on. I also tried

```
paste(name)<<-results.table
```

and

```
substitute(name)<<-results.table
```

to no avail. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is possible, but very un-R-like. Besides, it just clutters the global environment. Why do you want to do this? The whole point of `lapply` is that you end up with a list with one element for each in the original list. Easy to manipulate and search...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lapply()` is already intended to apply functions to each element of a list and return a list of the results - no need to have your function index that list.  I think this is what you're really getting at, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
# Define your function - no need for assignment here
myfunc<- function (data) {some.operations(data)}

# Apply your function to each element of dat - lapply returns a list with 
# an element of each result.  Instead of assigning each result globally,
# just assign this list of results
results <- lapply(dat, myfunc)
```

This way, you'll have another nice list of results that you can continue to operate on in the same way.  This approach is more typical for R - if you really, really need the objects assigned to the global environment, let us know why so we can better tailor our answers.

Comment: Right, somehow I forgot that I could do that. That is much simpler and  exactly what I needed. Thank you!